# Intersection of a family of compact sets in Hausdorff topological space is compact

Tags: compactness

Let $\{G_i\}_{i \in \Lambda}$ be a family of compact sets in a Hausdorff topological space. Show that the intersection $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i$ is compact.

My attempt was:

Since $G_j$ for some $j \in \Lambda$ is compact, there exists an open, finite covering. And $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i \subset G_j$. So I can take the same covering for the intersection as for $G_j.$

Is that correct?

Comment: No. You need to show that for **any** open cover of the intersection that there is a finite subcover. Hint, the intersection is closed.

Comment: You need that $\Lambda$ is not empty. Incidentally, this correction is also a hint

Comment: I've corrected my proof. May I ask you to have a look on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see my mistakes and realised that I misunderstood the definition of compactness. I would correct the proof as following:

Since a compact set in a Hausdorff topological space is closed, it follows that $G_i \forall i \in \Lambda$ is closed. Hence, $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i$ is closed. Now define $F:=(\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i)^{c}$ which is the complement. Note that $F$ is open.

Let $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ be an open covering of $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i$. My goal is to show that this covering is finite or has a finite sub-covering.

Note that $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \cup F$ is the whole space. In particular it is a covering of $G_{i_0}$ for $i_0 \in \Lambda$. By compactness of $G_{i_0}$ there exists finite $I' \subset I$ s.t. $G_{i_0} \subset $ $\bigcup_{i \in I'} U_i \cup F$.

Note that:

$\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i \subset G_{i_0} \subset  \bigcup_{i \in I'} U_i \cup F$. But since $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i \cap F = \emptyset$ we have that:

$\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i \subset \bigcup_{i \in I'} U_i$. So we have found a finite open covering and hence $\bigcap_{i \in \Lambda} G_i$ is compact.

Is that correct?

Comment: **Much** better! Yes, this works.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not correct. First, you seem to have misunderstood compactness. It does not say that a compact set has a finite open cover: in any space $X$ the family $\{X\}$ of open sets is a finite open cover of **every** subset of $X$, compact or not. It says that every open cover of a compact set has a finite subcover.

Secondly, you have not used the hypothesis that the space is Hausdorff, which is essential: the result is not true in general for non-Hausdorff spaces. Let $X$ be the line with two origins as described [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/the-line-with-two-origins/); then the sets $\{p\}\cup(0,1]$ and $\{q\}\cup(0,1]$ are compact subsets of $X$ whose intersection $(0,1]$ is not compact.

HINT: Show (if you’ve not already done so) that every compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed. What do you know about the intersection of closed sets? What do you know about closed subsets of compact sets?

Comment: I've corrected my proof in another answer. Does that work?